# Determine the integral closure of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> Let $R=F[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$. Determine the integral closure of $R$ in its quotient field.

I guess I should reduce the problem to some statement related to $F[X]$. For $F$ of characteristic not equal to 2, I proved that the integral closure is $F[X, \sqrt{X}]$. But how to work with the case when $\mathrm{char}(F)=2$?

Comment: I don't know what you did, but characteristic shouldn't be a problem here. Note that $F[X, \sqrt{X}] = F[\sqrt{X}]$ is integrally closed and is an integral extension of $R$ no matter of the characteristic of $F$. Hence the answer is the same.

Comment: We proved that for a Dedekind domain $R$ with $2$ invertible in $R$,  if for an nonzero element $d\in R$, the ideal $dR$ is not divisible by the square of a prime ideal, then the ring $R[\sqrt{d}]$ is Dedekind. From this, it can be proved that $R[\sqrt{X}]$ is the integral closure, but I need that $F$ is not of characteristic $2$.

Comment: You don't need all that Dedekind domain machinery. Call $S=F[\sqrt{X}]$. Is it integrally closed? Yes (because it is isomorphic to $F[T]$, which is a PID). Is it an integral extension of $R$? Yes. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R\simeq F[T^2,T^3]$ by $X\to T^2$, $Y\to T^3$. Since the integral closure of $F[T^2,T^3]$ is $F[T]$ we can conclude that the integral closure of $R$ is $R[\frac yx]=F[x,\frac yx]=F[x,\sqrt x]$.